# Unable to get service reference when uploaded to main website server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, web-applications

I am new to web services and I own a domain and a server to test my web-apps live. I tried to create a web-service that does a normal addition operation. It was running fine on localhost but as I published it to web-server, and accessed it using "Add Service Reference" in Visual Studio 2012 as http://www.mydomain.com/RequestServer/WebService.asmx it gave me `Resource not found` error

The RequestServer is the folder at my webserver that contains this web-service. So I want to know that:

1. What server settings should be done to access web-service?
2. What is the correct way to access the web-service?

Please tell me am I missing some important step?

Comment: You have to say much more about your config to allow us to help you. Is the domain name ok ? Is your remote IIS running ? What's his config ?

Comment: Ya my web server is running and domain name is ok, my website opens perfectly from this domain. And what specific config you are asking for IIS?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786110/resource-not-found-when-trying-to-invoke-web-service-method) ?

Comment: Also do you have any error logs on the server side ? Have you tried to sniff the communication with fiddler and call the ws-* with it ?

Comment: Actually I solved it myself. The problem was there was another web.config in parent folder. So I just shifted the whole service to a sub-domain(a new website) instead.

Comment: Nice that you've found a solution

Answer (score 0):

For WCF in 2010 and IIS 7,

You need to set the **serviceMetadata** tag, located in the following hierarchy of your web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
```

This will enable meta data publishing, which allows the service reference feature to work.

I assume this will be same in 2012 and whatever build of IIS you are using.